# Why there is lack of momentum in Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: mongodb, redis, couchdb, amazon-simpledb, nosql

I am working on a project and as I want it to be hassle free so I am considering using Amazon SimpleDB for the sake of simplicity. At least I can cross out DB administration.

But why there is so little info about SimpleDB on the net? As if nobody cares about it and I feel like I might be on the wrong track. Is it so unpopular? The other major NoSQL databases have a lot more coverage. What could be the reason? Is it because it is hosted? Does it lack major important features which I don't notice? Is it horrible performance-wise? Is it not durable? Why people are not very interested? Are there better alternatives for hosted NoSQL?

Comment: Your question will probably get closed, but the deal breaker for me was the 2k per column limitation.  For storing any real data, you had to do all sorts of hacks like AND together a bunch of columns or something.  I said forget that, and went Mongo.  Maybe they changed that limitation, I never bothered to check again.

Comment: @celalo A link to developer forum - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=38 A link to developer guide - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html?r=1777 Tool for Amazon SimpleDB (free for 30 days) - http://www.sdbexplorer.com/. Open source project http://code.google.com/p/typica/ and AWS JAR - http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/. Please let me know if you would like to know more.